# ShopifyAPI::Image ActiveResource::ResourceInvalid (Failed.)

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

Not sure why I cannot save new Shopify image. No specific error in response, i don't know if i missed some required field or used obsolete one.

Gem used:

```
gem "shopify_api", "9.5.1"
gem "shopify_app", "18.1.3"
```

Here's my code:

```
image = ShopifyAPI::Image.new
image.position = 2
image.variant_ids = []
image.prefix_options[:product_id] = "7484171813049"
image.src = "https://sample_only/image.jpg" # => i also tried image.url
image.save! 

# => ActiveResource::ResourceInvalid (Failed.)
```

Comment: If I were you, I would use Shopify API > v12, and Shopify App > v21.4 

Those versions you specify are old and not supported moving forward, and you'll quickly find you're wasting time, as everything you do will have to be abandoned and updated soon enough anyway.

Comment: Hi @DavidLazar - thank you, we'll be updating soon but for now we're fixing small things before going to big change :)